# Scalability of GeoHash Based proximity services

Tags: postgresql, postgis, software-design, geohashing

I was reading the *Proximity Service* chapter in *System Design Volume 2* by Alex Xu, where one of the approaches for locating businesses near a specific location involved using "GeoHashes".

However, when using this approach to find nearby businesses, a `LIKE` query is necessary, such as

```sql
WHERE geohash LIKE '9qbwac%'
```

Despite having an index on the geohash column in Postgres, this query will trigger a full table scan. As the number of businesses grows, a full table scan could significantly slow down the process. Hence, is this approach truly better?

I tried building a dummy table in Postgres with index on the geoHash column and inserted 1 million random entries. Running a `WHERE` clause with `LIKE` operator does full table scan.

Comment: Use text_pattern_ops.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html

Comment: @jjanes Can you recommend a text similarity function closest to what would be a geohash distance? Prefix checks pretty much limit things to an equivalent of `st_dwithin()` and I suspect I'm missing something simple, probably based on left-to-right weighted char-by-char `ascii()` values. The trgrm `<->` I used below is inadequate, eyeballing at best

Comment: @Zegarek No, I was just answering about the index search using LIKE.  I don't know much about geocode, and from what I do know don't really understand the point.  I'd just use basic postgis indexing capabilities if I were doing it.

Comment: Aside from clearly outperforming it, even testing geohash was easier using PostGIS `ST_Geohash()`, so I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you didn't set up the right index that would be able to support queries based on `like` or [`^@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), as already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639350/scalability-of-geohash-based-proximity-services#comment136875210_77639350) by [@jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes). Here's an example [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dGVnvYYV), comparing operations based on geohash vs regular [PostGIS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/spatial-search-geometry-and-gist-combination-outperforms-geohash-and-b-tree_597174) geometries. For prefix checks, `text_pattern_ops` will be enough, but I went with [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) to also compare `<->` [distance](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)/[similarity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE) measurements (ignoring the fact that's not really the way to compute distance based on a geohash).

PostGIS:

```sql
prepare postgis_based2 as
select id,business_name,x,y,geohash
from business
where st_dwithin((select geom from business where id=42),geom,1)
limit 5;

explain analyze execute postgis_based2;
execute postgis_based2;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=8.71..93.30 rows=5 width=62) (actual time=0.114..0.120 rows=5 loops=1) |
| InitPlan 1 (returns $0) |
| -> Index Scan using business_pkey on business business_1 (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (id = 42) |
| -> Index Scan using geom_idx on business (cost=0.41..169.58 rows=10 width=62) (actual time=0.112..0.118 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (geom && st_expand($0, '1'::double precision)) |
| Filter: st_dwithin($0, geom, '1'::double precision) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 1 |
| Planning Time: 0.367 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.187 ms |

| id | business_name | x | y | geohash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22307 | business_22307 | 165.213429396186 | -45.3420063495878 | pxvqp98xxvmudmj97vkf |
| 83713 | business_83713 | 164.855609921369 | -45.0914942385985 | pxvprrk5n0hr95qn5u8w |
| 93720 | business_93720 | 164.990241156698 | -45.0564514554435 | pxvrdmwppk8tgw7n39vb |
| 42 | business_42 | 164.28489159467 | -45.2105222171467 | pxuyf3ste7vf53zk17fj |
| 6309 | business_6309 | 164.818000468193 | -45.2836125675001 | pxvnqs2gcfb9hsmg5tru |

---

Geohash:

```sql
prepare geohash_based2 as
select id,business_name,x,y,geohash
from business
where geohash like (select left(geohash,2)||'%' from business where id=42)
limit 5;

explain analyze execute geohash_based2;
execute geohash_based2;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Limit (cost=8.60..26.28 rows=5 width=62) (actual time=0.124..0.229 rows=5 loops=1) |
| InitPlan 1 (returns $0) |
| -> Index Scan using business_pkey on business business_1 (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (id = 42) |
| -> Index Scan using business_geohash_idx on business (cost=0.28..1769.03 rows=500 width=62) (actual time=0.123..0.227 rows=5 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (geohash ~~ $0) |
| Planning Time: 0.117 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.246 ms |

| id | business_name | x | y | geohash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6455 | business_6455 | 161.767801616675 | -45.6640432705416 | pxgh1p5ewvre95j5rkyx |
| 987 | business_987 | 157.535974430581 | -46.4991816873455 | px8p2z44wk22zke1jqpm |
| 21938 | business_21938 | 157.564399796883 | -45.6057628837771 | pxbh93wzhtegxh8m2kv9 |
| 97368 | business_97368 | 162.477336834207 | -50.1455647066609 | px5d9r22um5qfvt4msbs |
| 42804 | business_42804 | 167.725818809955 | -47.204996981719 | pxx72ww4yyg0svjhde6e |